# Django ORM order by the in operator list

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, list, django-orm

the title explains it all. I need to filter my model for all elements of a list.

```
Event.objects.filter(name__in=d)
```

how can i sort the result according to the order of the elements of list d?
I tried with

```
[e for t in d for e in events if e.name == t]
```

but it is really slow. is there what other faster option?

Comment: Use the ORM order_by instead of ordering it yourself.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by